# ぐらい + が meaning

Tags: particle-が, song-lyrics, particle-くらい

https://www.lyrical-nonsense.com/lyrics/haku/shoudou/

From this song:

> 焦らすぐらいがあなたは好きでしょ？

Why is が added after ぐらい? Is it because of omitting the subject （私）?
焦らすぐらい（私）があなたは好きでしょ？

And, is my translation correct:

> You like me so much that you want to tease me ?

Answer (score 3):

> 「焦{じ}らすぐらい**が**あなた**は**好{す}きでしょ？ 」

I am still wondering how I should start my explanation here because your translation attempt:

> "You like me so much that you want to tease me ?"

is way off, I am afraid.

First of all, you need to understand that 「焦らすぐらい」 is functioning as a **noun**, which is why it can directly precede the 「が」.  Make a (mental) mistake here and it will cost you the rest of the sentence.

> 「Word / Phrase + くらい + **が** + 好き / いい, etc.」

is the sentence pattern we are looking at and it is a commonly used one as well.

「Word / Phrase + くらい」 in that pattern means:

> "(something) coming nearer in quality to (word or phrase)"

In other words, it means:

> "(something) bordering on (word or phrase)"

Thus, this structure is generally used to describe an amount of deviation from the normal and how it is preferred over the normal.

In the sentence in question, that "something" is unmentioned, but it should refer to "the way I treat you", "the way I love you", etc.
The word/phrase is 「焦らす」 ("to tease").

Thus, my own TL would be:

> "You like it when (the way I treat you) borders on teasing, dontcha?"

Other examples:

- 「コーヒーは少{すこ}し苦{にが}いくらい**が**ボク**は**好きです。」

"I like my coffee to taste a bit bitter (than average/normal)."

- 「女性{じょせい}アイドルは多少{たしょう}ぽっちゃりしてるくらい**が**丁度{ちょうど}いい。」

"As for female idols, I (tend to) prefer the ones that are just a little bit overweight."

Comment: Can it be translated to "You like (something missing) to the extent of teasing" ?

Comment: "You like it when (the way I treat you) borders on teasing, dontcha?" I'm just a little bit confused with this sentence. Could you rewrite it another way ?